# How much praise can be found max in one run through Okami?

Tags: okami

I want to complete all extras in Okami. But I cannot sure to have found all. So I want to ask, how much Praise you can gain in the game? If I get this, I know I found all stuff. I don't really want a walkthrough, because I want to find the things myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a single play through it's rumored to be in the range of 7240, I've seen folks hit 7200 and up. The counter stops at 9,999. (it will cary over on replay.)